# Enabling file_get_contents on a shared server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am using  `file_get_contents('http://example.com');`

I get the error

```
'function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in
```

I know i have to enable  `allow_url_fopen` in php file. The problem is that i am on a shared server am i am having acesss viz ftp but i cant locate where the file is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, if [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is disabled, there is no way you can enable it.  Only the root user can edit the `php.ini` file which would control that setting.

You can request your host enable it, or see if [cURL](http://php.net/curl) is enabled on the shared server.

Comment: Where is the file PHP.INI located on the server ?
I could not find it in /Etc and i could not find any directory named /usr/

I saw some where written if i edit the .HTaccess file with  allow_url_fopen 1 it should work, but this gives me an Internal server Error

Comment: If you make a file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it, it will tell you the location of the `php.ini` file being used.  Using htaccess can give you a server error if PHP is not an Apache module and is configured as a CGI instead.  allow_url_fopen cannot be changed in `.htaccess` though, only `php.ini` and `httpd.conf` which you will not have access to.